# read text file into vector string android/java

Tags: android, string, text, vector

I've read about one trillion answers to this question that don't involve using a vector of strings. I need a function that will read words from a text file one by one into a data structure that I can call later on. Or, I need a function that can read words from a text file one by one and store them in three separate lists in one data structure.

```
private Vector<String> getLetters(String chapter, int t) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(com.example.android.myprojecte.R.raw.aa);
        Vector<String> letters = null;  
        InputStreamReader isReaded = new InputStreamReader(is);


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReaded);
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            letters.add(line);
         }

        return letters;
 }
```

Basically, I just need to read a text file into a vector string, but my emulator keeps crashing. It could be something with my fragments, but the error code is signifying it's an I/O problem? So is this wrong above please and thank you

edit: i am pretty sure that the error is a null pointer exception

edit2: i restarted eclipse and i have a ton of errors in other parts of my code... i think this part is fine.

answer: I created a new blank project, added is.close() and br.close() statements, and declared the variable inside a different function since i had no idea what i was doing. Not sure which of these worked but declaring right after main activity didn't work like the guy suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate letters.  `letters = new Vector<String>();`

Comment: i still get null pointer exception... Did you mean I need to do this at the top of my code? like right after "public class MainActivity extends Activity"